# Howto add validation in listview in sugarcrm7?

Tags: sugarcrm

I need to add validation for field:Phone to prevent adding text into phone field in SugarCRM 7.5
is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Saad,
I did it by following solution:

1. Create a new custom field
2. Add my own mask input into `_render()` and `initialize` function
3. I added keypress event into custom field controller to prevent press invalid characters (symbols,....)
4. I added mustache files to showing proper values in edit,list view,...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by different solutions:

1. Include JQuery Mask plugin and apply validation on all phone type fields.
2. Create custom field type for phone and apply validation.
3. Sugar has provided field validation for record view you can also get help from it [link](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.5/20_UI_Model/30_Views/Examples/Adding_Field_Validation_to_the_Record_View/).

Here is related [link](https://community.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm/topics/validate-feilds-in-listview-in-sugarcrm7-5) to your question